# combining pandas dataframe with multiple time series of different length

Tags: python, pandas

I've got one pandas dataframe df which looks like:

```
      date  aaa     date.1  bbb …       date.n   nnn
31.12.2001  3.0 31.12.2002  6.0 …   31.12.1990  10.2
  1.1.2002  3.1   1.1.2003  6.3 …     1.1.1991  10.1
```

The time series are of different length. I'd like to have one single column date and the data aaa, bbb, ... ,nnn thereafter. Whenever there is no value for a given date, simply NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while, but I found the answer:

```
df.columns = [(np.arange (len(df.columns)) // 2).astype (str), df.columns]
df1 = [x.set_index(x.columns[0]).dropna() 
     for i, x in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1)]
df2 = pd.concat(df1, axis=1)
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('_'.join)
```